# How to create a model that can have multiple labels associated to it?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification

I have a set of news paper report.
I need to classify them as Sports, Politics related at first.
Once the given document is in Sports category, then I need to furthur classify them as Football, Cricket, Tennis etc. For Politics it's International, National, Local etc.

Again I would like assign a positive, negative class on this  sub category result.

So for a given document ouput will be something like :

```
Document- >[Main_Category, Sub_Category, Sentiment] 
Document_101 ->[Sports, Football, Positive]
```

What is the best approcah to create a model for this case ?

Shall I create different models for each of this class (sports, politics, cricket, international, positive, negative etc) ?
If yes then is it possible to create a [pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) of each class prediction ?

Or is it advisable to trian a single model per each output like sports_cricket_positive,s ports_cricket_negative etc

Comment: Do you know about inverse index and word2vec?

Comment: Yes but how those are related tho this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. chaining 12 classifiers together. First to split between $Sport$ and $Politics$ then further classify each of them.
   I find this redundant and their might not be enough training data for each model.
2. using sub-class labels to train data, as you mentioned. 
   This [paper](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~achim/PDFs/ECML01.pdf) shows decision tress(C4.5) perform better when we have more classes to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

For classifying a document into Main_Category and Sub_Category, you can use a hierarchical approach. First classify into main category (Sports, Politics, etc.), then classify into sub-category based on the main category (if Sports, then one of Football, Cricket, Tennis, etc.) This gives you the flexibility of choosing the classifier that works best at a given level of hierarchy.

For sentiment, it is likely that the way sentiment is expressed is common to several categories, so in a sense this is "orthogonal" to category. You could learn a classifier on Positive vs Negative sentiment, using data from all categories together.

So you will have a chain of two classifiers -> Main_Category, Sub_Category, and a single classifier -> Sentiment, that you will combine to get the final result.